# UWP Vertical Scrollbar with fixed header

Tags: uwp

In an UWP I would like to have a fixed header line containing some buttons on the top of my App. The rest of the screen should be vertically scrollable (like a fixed navigation).

This is my code so far:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <RelativePanel>
            <Button x:Name="btntest" Content="fixed button"/>
        </RelativePanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollView" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <StackPanel Padding="0,30,0,0">
                   [...my Content...]
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

It does not do what I want, because the scrollbar is shown, but the content (higher than the screen) cannot be scrolled.

How can I gain my goal - how do I have to arrange Panels (Stack, Relative?) and the ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood you correct and you want a fixed header above your scrollviewer, then you should be able to achieve this either by using vertical *StackPanel* or by using *Grid* with suitable rows (everything depends on your needs). Sample:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" x:Name="btntest" Content="fixed button"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyScrollView" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <StackPanel Padding="0,30,0,0">
            [...my Content...]
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you Romasz - that is exactly what I wanted and I see my error in my code above - I cascaded too much :/